# A directory showing up in itself

Tags: ls, directory-structure, pwd

I do `cd ~` and then `pwd`. It shows `/root`. Then I do `ls`. It again shows `root`. This is NOT another directory with the same name because when I do `cd root`, it says `-bash: cd: root: Not a directory`.

Somehow, I have messed up something.

**UPDATE:**
The output of `ls -l ~/root` is:

`-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 215040 Oct 15 10:01 /root/root`

The output of `ls -ld /root/root` is:

`-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 215040 Oct 15 10:01 /root/root`

The output of `file /root/root` is:

`/root/root: POSIX tar archive (GNU)`

Comment: `ls -l ~/root` will probably show that you have a regular file there named “root”

Comment: Please show (in the question) the output of `ls -ld /root/root`.

Comment: @Kusalananda  I have added the output of the command.

Comment: @a_fan please add also output of command `file /root/root`

Comment: @mrc02_kr added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/root/root` thing is a *file* (not a directory) which additionally looks like a `tar` archive.

If you wish to list the contents of that archive, use

```
tar -tvf /root/root
```